# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown provider: SampleDataProvider

Tags: html, angularjs

I am having trouble understanding what I am doing wrong with importing json data into my application. I dont see any get calls in the console tools and I keep getting a $injector:unpr error. I have written this code in the controller.js

```
  function caderror($scope, SampleData) {

        // Run method getFullList() from factory
        SampleData.getFullList().success(function(data){

            // Assign data to $scope
            $scope.dataFromFactory = data;
        });

    }
```

and here is factories.js where the sample data is reffering to.

```
function SampleData($http) {

        // Return the object
        return {

            // Create simple method to get data from $http service
            getFullList : function() {
                return $http({
                    url: 'http://somewebsite/api/example.json',
                    method: 'GET'
                })
            }
        }

    }



angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .factory('SampleData', SampleData);
```

Here is the HTML I am using to call the JSON data into a table

```
<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <h2>CAD Error Logs</h2>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Tables</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <strong>Data Tables</strong>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="text-center m-t-lg">
                <h1>
                    Simple factory to get data from server
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">

            <div class="ibox">
                <div class="ibox-content">

                    <p class="text-center">
                        Table with data from api/example.json
                    </p>

                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Id
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Company
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Description
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in dataFromFactory">
                            <td>
                                {{item.id}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{item.name}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{item.company}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{item.desc}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong and if any more code is needed please let me know and i will post it. I read up on the error and it says it caused by being unable to resolve a required dependency. How would I go about fixing this. the error site of angular js didnt really help me.

---

EDIT

Here is the error message

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=SampleDataProvider%20%3C-%20SampleData%20%3C-"aderror

I could show the rest but they are just file lines in angular.min.js

Comment: angular tag is for Angular 2+ This looks like AngularJS - the older version

Comment: yes it is! I will untag the tag for angular 2

Comment: If changing the service code doesn't work, can you post the entire error message including the url that it contains?

Comment: please post the error message you are getting.  "I read up on the error" doesn't tell us anything about the problem.

Comment: ok  I will post it. It is very long tho lol

Comment: also, you should consider not using `.success`, it is deprecated.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6

Comment: if possible, use angular.js rather than angular.min.js, which will produce a more readable and probably shorter error message.

Comment: awesome ok thanks, when you say rather use angular.js what are you referring to. Sorry very nooby trying to learn as much as I can . Will post the error message now

Comment: I am referring to `<script src="angular.js">` rather than `<script src="angular.min.js">`

Comment: ahhh ok will do that now

Comment: from that error, it looks like maybe you didn't include the file that has `SampleData` in the scripts?  it's hard to tell since you aren't showing which files this code is in, or which files (and which order) they are included in your HTML.

Comment: I tried posting a plunkr but there was so many files I didnt want to overwhelm people with data. Basically I know the JSON file is there because I put it there however in the console for mozilla im not seing a get request for the example.json any idea why that may be?

Comment: Here is the error using angular.js

Comment: "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SampleDataProvider <- SampleData <- caderror
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=SampleDataProvider%20%3C-%20SampleData%20%3C-"aderror

Comment: Also any other files that you would like to see let me know and I will post it as a edit to the original question

Comment: not the JSON file;  the file you refer to here as `factories.js`;  where in your HTML is the `<script src="factories.js">`, and what other scripts are loading before and after it?

Comment: the function `caderror` is looking for `SampleData` but can't find it, which generally means the code for `SampleData` isn't included (the script is missing) or the script is in the wrong order.

Comment: YAYYYYY!!!!!! so i feel very dumb but I am so grateful for all your help. I did not have the script include in index.html -__- its been a long day

Comment: if you want to post the answer as include script in index.html i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error commonly occurs due to a problem with your `<script>` references.

The error is telling us that the function `caderror` is looking for `SampleData` but can't find it.  This most commonly occurs when the file containing the code for `SampleData` is not included in the `<script>` references, or is listed *after* the file that needs it (the file with `caderror` in it, in this case).

Also, you should consider not using `.success()` in your methods, since it has been deprecated.  See [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6)